# User Access to folder on Linux Server

Tags: linux, ssh

I created a user using the useradd command. I'm attempting to give user2 (newly created) access to user1's folder. I added user2 to the same group as user1 (using usermod -g), but when I attempt to change the home directory or open the directory, I get a "permission denied" message. This is my first attempt in trying this, so I assume I'm missing a step. What do I need to do to change a user's home directory and gain permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups are only an "abstract concept" for create a set of permissions on a certain resource. 
If you want to give `user2` read permission above `user1` home directory, and if you want to do this with groups, you have also to give at the whole group the `+x` permission on that directory.

So, you could do something like this: `chmod g+x /homeDirectoryOfUserA`

Answer (score 0):

`user2` needs at least execute (`x`) permission on all parent folders of the folder that you want to allow access to.

Read (`r`) isn't necessary; that would also allow the user to list those folders. So to open `/home/user1/x`, the permissions must be at least:

```
*****x*** /home
***--x--- /home/user1
***r*x--- /home/user1/folder
```

Legend: `*` can be anything, `-` means "not set"

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign user2 to the group that owns the directory. If you run `ls -l` you will see the following format user:group. That's the owner of the directory/file. Make sure user2 is a member of that group. Then you will need to make sure the group has the necessary permissions. You can do this by running `chmod 775`. That will give the owner and group members full access, and everyone else read access.